# AngularJS: ngResource and array of object as params to URL

Tags: angularjs

I have variable `$scope.data= [{column:"age", operator: ">", value: "50"}, {column:"name", operator: "=", value: "Tonda"}]`. And service for submitting data to server:

```
angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('serverApp', function($resource, $scope){
    return $resource('myurl/', {}, {
        saveData: {method:'POST', params: $scope.data}
    });
});
```

Why URL contains "nonsense" after calling `serverApp.saveData()? - .../myurl?**0=%5Bobject+Object%5D&1=%5Bobject+Object%5D** - It seems, that params can be only simple (1D) object.

How can I properly serialize object `$scope.cfgcondition` into params of service `serverApp` (eg. to URL)? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's calling a GET for some reason. As the params are in the URL rather than the body.

Comment: Probably need to see more code. Like where you're calling it from.

Answer (score 18):

The 'params' attribute defines URL query params, which I assume is intended behavior. If it was just a simple object, not an array, then you could just use $save something like

```
var MyRequest = $resource('/notreally'); 
$scope.data = new MyRequest;
// get stuff into $scope.data
$scope.doSubmit = function() { $scope.data.$save(); }
```

To post an array you need to define your own action and pass the data in as second parameter.

```
$scope.data= [{column:"age", operator: ">", value: "50"}, 
              {column:"name", operator: "=", value: "Tonda"}]; 
var MyRequest = $resource('/notreally', {}, {saveData: {method:'POST', isArray: true}}); 
$scope.doSubmit = function() { MyRequest.saveData({}, $scope.data);
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

*Edited to fix misstatements regarding arrays - I thought $resource could not POST arrays, but figured out that I was wrong!