# how to pass an array from angular js to REST service using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am a novice to AngularJs and REST service and want to know how can I pass an array of object to REST-POST call in angular js using $resource.
I know how to pass a single parameter but not sure how to pass an array. This is my code for Get call where I am passing a single parameter. Can anyone tell me , how can I achieve the same thing with POST + array. Thanks!!

```
 var services = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);
        services.factory('AngularIssues',
            function($resource){
            return $resource('http://localhost:8181/MyRESTService/services/UserInfo/:id', {} ,{
                get:{method:'GET' , params: {id: '@id'} }
             } );
        });
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002560/angularjs-ngresource-and-array-of-object-as-params-to-url

Comment: @tenthfloor - I tried the solution posted in your code but I am getting this error  "No message body reader has been found for request class List, ContentType : application/octet-stream". Basically my REST service is expecting a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you'll need to do something like this. Where you are passing your POST request as a parameter of the `save()` function. Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9c74N/2/). You can verify this using Chrome's Dev Tools under Networks.

Have a look at the [AngularJS $resource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), there are some examples of how to make a POST call to the API.

```
services.factory('AngularIssues',
function($resource){
   return $resource('/echo/json/', {} ,{
       get:{method:'GET' , params: {id: '@id'} }
   } );
});

services.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'AngularIssues', 
function($scope, AngularIssues) {

    AngularIssues.save({ "theArray": [{ name: "Object 1" }, { name: "Object 2" }] })
    .$promise.then(function(res) {
       $scope.done = "I AM DONE!";
    });

}]);
```

Comment: @J.P.Armstrong-> I tried this code and getting error "No message body reader has been found for request class List, ContentType : application/octet-stream"   `$scope.data1= [{employeeId:"12345", firstName: "Neon", lastName: "Milan",designation:"Business Analyst" , department:"Dep",salary:"*******",rating:"1" , joiningDate:"11/2/2007" , employeeType:"permanent" , manager:"aaaa" }];

 UpdatePopulation.saveData({}, $scope.data1); `                        
 My REST service expects a list.

Comment: Update your question with the code, where are you defining: `UpdatePopulation.saveData({}, $scope.data1);`

Comment: Thanks J.P.Armstrong and @tenthfloor!! Both of your answers have helped me and I am finally able to send array in request body to REST service using $resource.