# Transform request data with resource service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to send just the array of my data to the server.  I found this post discussing how to send an array, but I can't get it to work.

[AngularJS: ngResource and array of object as params to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002560/angularjs-ngresource-and-array-of-object-as-params-to-url)

The problem I am having is my resource gets sent back to me as JSON like this

```
{
Results: []
}
```

So when I ask for my resources,

```
    var collaboratorResource = api.CollaboratorList.get({Id: Id });
```

but then, if I try something like

```
collaboratorResource.$save($scope.collaborators);
```

When I look at firebug, it shows that my data is being sent as

```
{
Results: []
}
```

when in reality, I don't want to send the data as an object with the array as a Results property.  I want to send it just as an array `[]`.  I need to do that since the api is legacy and expects that.

I've been trying to see if transformRequest works, like if I did

```
collaboratorResource.$save({data: $scope.collaborators, transformRequest: function (data, headers) { return data.results; }});
collaboratorResource.$save({}, $scope.collaborators);
collaboratorResource.$save($scope.collaborators);
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.  Is this even possible?  As an aside, if I use $http like this, it works:

```
$http({ method: "POST", data: $scope.collaborators, url: collaboratorUrl });
```

I'm just not sure how to use the $resource service properly since I'd prefer to wrap everything in $resource if possible and not have a hybrid of both if possible.

Comment: Just a guess, try this syntax: `collaboratorResource.$save({}, $scope.collaborators, function(result) {`

Comment: @tymeJV With that, the data is still sent as `{results:[]}`

Comment: Ahh damn...alright, give this a whirl: `collaboratorResource.$save($scope.collaborators)` - omitting the `{}` should just attach the array to the body.

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah I tried that as well.  I forgot to put that in my question.  Will edit it.

Comment: Double damn...I had this same issue a bit ago and ended up just using `$http` - hopefully someone has a solution.