# How to pass array parameter to AngularJS $resource

Tags: angularjs

When I pass an array to a resource action.. it doesn't convert the array parameter to an array of URL parameters

```
var Product = $resource('path/products');
Product.query({ids: [1,2,3]})
```

Instead of getting:

```
path/products?ids[]=1&ids[]=2ids[]=3
```

I'm getting:

```
path/products?ids=1&ids=2ids=3
```

Anyone knows how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use $resource to pass array

```
var searchRequest = $resource('/api/search/post', {}, {
    'get': {method: 'GET'}
});
searchRequest.get({'ids[]':[1,2,3]});
```

then you get request url

```
/api/search/post?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3
```

you get `%5B%5D` instead of `[]`

and if you expect return `array` instead of `object` then you should use

```
'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
```

Comment: nice, thanks! but why would you label your GET route `/post`? xD

Comment: you saved my life!

Answer (score -1):

Params should be declared like this

```
var Product = $resource('path/products?:ids',
{ids: '@ids'});
```

However I am not sure what resulting url you want to achieve. Any of the posted in OP ways is an invalid request, because of repeating parameter.

To stick to GET verb and define an array in query params I see the only way: to construct param as a string

```
var query = [1,2,3].map(function(el){return 'brand[]='+el}).join('&');
Product.query({ids: query});
```

**PS** Unless you have strong reasons the best approach would be to send arrays using POST verb, like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002560/angularjs-ngresource-and-array-of-object-as-params-to-url). With array sent over URL you can easily run out of maximum URL length

Comment: sorry, what does OP mean?

Comment: Based on the query, the parameter 'ids' is used to filter the resource.. the parameter can be 'category_id', 'brand_id', etc..  And the parameter can be an array to signify you want to filter the result by these brands for example (e.g: /path/products?brand[]=A&brand[]=B)

Comment: passing the parameter multiple times without using [] would overwrite the previous parameter passed. such as for the url "/path/products?brand=A&brand=B". the value of brand on the server would be 'B' not an array ['A','B'] because the first parameter brand which holds 'A' gets overwritten by the second brand parameter holding 'B'

Comment: OP means Original Post or Original Poster based on context

Comment: so does this mean the url "/path/products?brand[]=A&brand[]=B" is not RESTful?

Comment: i even didn't know of such a way of defining array params in GET query. I consider it is unpopular because of it's inefficiency. You can quickly run out of max query length for a GET request. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002560/angularjs-ngresource-and-array-of-object-as-params-to-url) how to pass array using POST. That would be my advice

Comment: If you're sure you want to stick to GET verb and use the syntax you mentioned, I guess you will have to provide value for `ids` as a string which you construct the way it is required

Comment: @Jasper updated answer, function code, doesn't fit comments format